# Date picker dialog not showing selected date when dialog reopened

Tags: java, android, datepicker, dialog

I am working on date picker dialog android. I am able to display the selected date and rest all working fine but when I am selecting a date, hitting ok and then reopening the dialog,the pointer goes back to the min date but not the selected date. I want to it to show the last selected date.

How do I fix this?

This opens the dialog when I the user clicks

```
public void show() {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
          PostInfoUpdate.this,
          now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
          now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
          now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );

    dpd.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
    dpd.setMaxDate(now);
    dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
}
```

This are callback methods

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    DatePickerDialog dpd
        = (DatePickerDialog) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Datepickerdialog");

    if(dpd != null) {
        dpd.setOnDateSetListener(this);
    }
}

public void setOnDateSetListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
        mCallBack = listener;
    }
```

This is where I set the date

```
 @Override
 public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
     String date = "You picked the following date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(++monthOfYear)+"/"+year;
     dateTextView.setText(date);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `show` method you are creating a fresh instance of  a `Calender` object and you are passing it to `DatePicker`. So it will always show the current date. If you want the selected date to shown, then have a global calender object and pass it datePicker, and also keep on updating it inside `onDateSet`. Something like below:

```
//Global variable, you can initialize inside OnCreate Method 
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

public void show() {

DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
      PostInfoUpdate.this,
      now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
      now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
      now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
);

dpd.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance());
now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
dpd.setMaxDate(now);
dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
}


@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
 String date = "You picked the following date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(++monthOfYear)+"/"+year;
 dateTextView.setText(date);
 now.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
 now.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
 now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Added a code sample in my updated answer, please check.

Comment: Hello, Im using joda time to get the current date and time, not using the calender. How do i have the datepicker set the selected value after reopening it for the second time?

Comment: when the date is selected, just update the joda time object and re-use the same object while opening the date picker. Please give me some code  for more explaination.